# Is interpreting Noah's flood as a civilization-wide event compatible with Roman Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, flood-of-noah

I heard an idea a while back that perhaps the flood described in the Old Testament wasn't necessarily a global, worldwide flood, but that it was a worldwide flood in a *human civilization* sense. In other words, it wouldn't have been necessary to flood the whole world in order to accomplish God's purpose of destroying corrupt humanity because humanity hadn't yet covered the whole world.

Is such a view compatible with the Catholic Church's teachings on Genesis?

Comment: Catholics dogmatize Negetively,  If for example the Catholic Church was to state with it's authority that the flood was world wide, then it would be binding to the Chruch and could be proven incorrect,  The Church leaves that thing up to the individual.  It is important however to understand that the event did happen, and the significance of that event, no matter what the scope of the flood was.  is the same.

Comment: @Marc: "It is important however to understand that the event did happen" -- that's a dogma itself, which would appear to contradict your statement.

Comment: @Flimzy  CCC 1219 The Church has seen in Noah's ark a prefiguring of salvation by Baptism, for by it "a few, that is, eight persons, were saved through water":14

The waters of the great flood 
you made a sign of the waters of Baptism, 
that make an end of sin and a new beginning of goodness.

That is the official position of the Catholic Church.  As far as I know there is no Dogma on the flood.  

Catholic Dogmas listed here: http://jloughnan.tripod.com/dogma.htm

Comment: @Marc: My point is that you say "no dogma exists," then state a dogma (that "the event did happen"). Both can't be true simultaneously. If your link is inclusive of all Catholic dogma, then that the flood did happen is *not* a given, according to the church (which would make sense, according to your statement about Catholic dogma, but would contradict your statement that "it is important however to understand that the event did happen.")

Comment: @Flimzy You don't seem to understand what Dogma is, for example, If heretics started to pronounce and teach truths contrary to revealed doctrine such as any one of the Dogma's listed in my link above.  The Church will formally make a dogmatic pronouncement concerning the event in question so that the faithful would know what to believe.  With Noah and the Flood, there has been no need to do such a thing as everyone who believes in the Gospel understands that there was a flood of some significance prefiguring Baptism and its neccesity in Gods Economy.

Comment: @Marc: I understand perfectly what dogma is. "a principle or set of principles laid down by an authority as incontrovertibly true." I also understand perfectly that your statement is false. "everyone who believes in the Gospel understands that there was a flood of some significance prefiguring Baptism and its neccesity in Gods Economy" That is simply not true. There are a good number of Christians who do not believe the flood literally happened.

Comment: @Flimzy are you suggesting that they believe there was not flood of any kind?  I often forget that Stack exchange defines Christian as pretty much anyone claiming to be a Christian.  My back yard flooded during hurricane Sandy, I can assure you and any other person, that floods do happen.  I have pictures.

Comment: @Marc: I'm not merely "suggesting it." I'm stating it as indisputable fact. Many consider the stories of the creation, the flood of Noah, the tower of Babel, The Exodus, and other stories, to be allegory or other varieties of myth.

Comment: (And unless you have photos of floods that required the evacuation of mating pairs of animals, for the survival of every species in the region, I'm afraid your photographic evidence isn't very relevant.)

Comment: @Flimzy I bleieve those poeple are called Humanists, teaching that there are no miricles in the bible, and that the teachings of Christ are simply addressing moral issues. The Catholic Church has no Problem with Allegory the manor that the allegory is understood by the church is not what you suggest. We must understand, that God distroyed the world(as percieved by the inspired author)and that 8 People survived that flood. Did God destroy the world where sinful man did not exist? Who is to say.  The Church leaves that to the faithful wisely as science seems to contridict a world wide flood.

Comment: @Marc: That's a gross over simplification. There's no obvious correlation between believing these stories are allegorical and that miracles don't happen. "We must understand, that God destroyed the world" -- Baloney. There are other interpretations of this story. The literal destruction of the "evil world" is not the only (nor the most important) theological meaning in this story. You are drawing entirely unfounded, and frankly, entirely ignorant and uneducated, conclusions. Put simply, *you don't know what you're talking about.*

Comment: And to be clear, I'm not here taking issue with your view that the flood was a literal event. I take issue with your assertion that this is the only "legitimate" interpretation. This is ignorance. Although it's not an uncommon ignorance. I encourage you to examine the issue of a literal flood, creation, Babel, Exodus, etc. Just because Evangelicals hold to these events as literal by no means should be taken to suggest that Christians by and large do. It just means that most Evangelicals aren't exposed to the alternate views (and may thus tend to believe that alternate views don't exist).

Comment: @flimzy Of course there are other interpretations. My interpretations are in line with apostalic tradition and understanding of the early Church which is the preservation of the interpretations handed down by a deposit of faith to the Church. You can interpret all day long, I wont argue with you, but when you do so, you do so without the literal understanding of the inspired Author. You are basically standing in front of Saint Paul and asking "So the flood didn't really happen Right?"  Ignorance comes from outside the Piller and Foundation of the Truth, not from withen it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29714/discussion-between-flimzy-and-marc).

Comment: Marc: See [this relevant answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/44158/20).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Catechism divides Scripture, according to *intent* of the writers, in the following ways:

> 115 According to an ancient tradition, one can distinguish between two senses of Scripture: the literal and the spiritual, the latter being subdivided into the allegorical, moral and anagogical senses. The profound concordance of the four senses guarantees all its richness to the living reading of Scripture in the Church.
>
> 116 The literal sense is the meaning conveyed by the words of Scripture and discovered by exegesis, following the rules of sound interpretation: "All other senses of Sacred Scripture are based on the literal."
>
> 117 The spiritual sense. Thanks to the unity of God's plan, not only the text of Scripture but also the realities and events about which it speaks can be signs.
>
> 1. The allegorical sense. We can acquire a more profound understanding of events by recognizing their significance in Christ; thus the crossing of the Red Sea is a sign or type of Christ's victory and also of Christian Baptism.
> 2. The moral sense. The events reported in Scripture ought to lead us to act justly. As St. Paul says, they were written "for our instruction".
> 3. The anagogical sense (Greek: anagoge, "leading"). We can view realities and events in terms of their eternal significance, leading us toward our true homeland: thus the Church on earth is a sign of the heavenly Jerusalem.
>
> 118 A medieval couplet summarizes the significance of the four senses:
>
> The Letter speaks of deeds; Allegory to faith;
> The Moral how to act; Anagogy our destiny.

As to the specific intention of the story of the flood, and thus the mode of interpretation under which the story would fall, like most other accounts of specific descriptions and verses in the bible, there is no 'official' doctrine regarding such matters. What is ascertained is that in any case the stories and the details as they were intended to be are true in such capacities. This means that in any one of the previous ways one wishes to interpret the flood story, it must in any way be true, rather than *partially true* or *false*.

Much of the beginnings of Genesis have been traditionally *allegorically* interpreted. To name only one example, St. Augustine thought of the 'light' that God made and divided from the 'darkness' could be meaningfully interpreted as the creation of angels. The allegorical approach to Genesis has the benefit of avoiding some problems that come with the more literal interpretations seen in many Protestant groups (which invariably leads to conflict between what appear to be inherent contradictions, and contradictions in science). But what is more important is that this approach also seems to garner greater meaning. Instead of being concerned with the literalness of whether God created the stars before 'light' or 'light' before the stars, we can focus more so on the meaning of these events, not simply as events in themselves but as potential symbols or phrases that carry greater theological weight. At the same time, the nature of the interpretation in such matters is existentially neutral to the fact of its existence. So whether or not the flood truly occurred, as in a sequence of events, need not deter our understanding of the story's meaning in an allegorical interpretation. This applies to all modes of interpretation. The Church is clear however that there are specific cases (the New Testament for example) in which our mode of interpretation must necessarily include the literalness of the specific events described. This also applies to the monogenism present in the Adam and Eve story, where the Church states it is necessary to recognize all human life essentially originates in its nature in two persons, who were created with original justice but who fell into sin, and who thereafter transposed such a fallen nature to mankind.

Thus, to answer more specifically the question, as to whether or not your specific understanding of the flood is aligned with the Catholic Church's stance on the story is somewhat of an arbitrary desire (though by no means unwarranted). The answer is that there isn't necessarily an answer. At most we can state that your interpretation must not deny the essential truth of the story, which is that God is both merciful and just, and enacts both essences in the deprived and sinful state of humanity. Furthermore, your interpretation must not deny that God speaks and breathes in His human creation through a covenant language, in which He is perfectly loving and just. These are the essential and primary purposes for which the story has been written, and as such it is these details that must not be left to individual interpretation, lest the perfect spiritual wisdom of Scripture be tainted by individual failures. In any such case of interpreting Scripture, the essential meaning and primary purpose of such Scriptures must be referred to the Church's Apostolic ministry for greater wisdom and authority, be such wisdom found in the present members or members of the past (there is a reason St. Augustine is so popular, and it's not due only to his cool name). And it is under canon law and the living Spirit that such ministers must be guided into wisdom.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This gave me a much firmer grasp on how the Church understands this event, as well as a good number of other Old testament events which I was rather unsure how to interpret.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: The allegorical approach to Genesis has the benefit of avoiding "...some problems that come with the more literal interpretations seen in many Protestant groups (which invariably leads to conflict between what appear to be inherent contradictions, and contradictions in science)".  -1 Why are you generalizing here. Give a single example...

Answer (score -1):

```
Is such a view compatible with the Catholic Church's teachings on Genesis?
```

It appears that this question is not about what the Church teaches, nor about what most Catholics are likely to believe, but merely whether it is compatible with Catholicism to believe that the biblical Flood was not a worldwide event.

[The Catholic encyclopedia](http://www.catholic.org/encyclopedia/view.php?id=8506) states that, among others, several Catholic scholars believe the Flood story preserves, ***under the embroidery of poetical parlance***, the memory of a fact handed down by a very old tradition. The Catholic encyclopedia says this view, were it supported by good arguments, could be readily accepted by a Catholic. The encyclopedia goes on to state that it has the advantage of suppressing as meaningless some difficulties once deemed unanswerable, compared to the  age-long opinion that every detail of the narration should be literally interpreted and trusted in by the historian. Although the Catholic encyclopedia is not an official organ of the Church and although the encyclopedia lends no support to the hypothesis, it does mean at least two things: that some Catholic scholars already believe that the story is based on memory of an ancient flood, coloured by poetic licence; that this view could be  accepted by a Catholic.

Ian Wilson, in *[Before the Flood: The Biblical Flood as a Real Event and How It Changed the Course of Civilization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312319711)* proposes that the story is actually based on the inundation of the Black Sea, formerly a rich agricultural area, at the end of the Ice Ages and provides detailed archaeological, historical and literary research to back up his thesis. This theory is undergoing further evaluation by archaeologists and others. Perhaps what Wilson describes was not a 'civilization-wide' flood but, should it be proven beyond reasonable doubt, the Catholic Church appears able to accept interpretations of the biblical Flood as a local event.